# Visual C++ debug commands don't debug a different application

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I tried using the debugger in Visual C++ 2010 Express on a few files to familiarize myself with the with breakpoints, step into, and etc. but many times if I use one of the step commands (at least step into) it will open another file like "ios" or "ostream" and do the command there instead of the actual program I'm working on. It seems to always happen after the last statement in my program and once it does it won't let me use the step commands on my own program anymore until I restart debugging. It's really annoying and sometimes it won't even let me use step into, over, or out even once. It will just open "ostream" or something and use it there.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stepping into the CRT (C++ Runtime). Hit Shift+F11 and you'll step out. You can avoid stepping into the runtime by right-clicking the line, and using the "Step into specific" option to step directly into your code